# selenium cant close MS edge after prompting a download

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, nightwatch.js

writing automated tests, I need to trigger a download.
Clicking the button to download, runs fine and all other assertions pass.
The problem is that edge will not allow selenium to close the browser when I call `browser.end()` because there is a dialog saying there is a download pending and is waiting for confirmation.
is there a flag or capability to allow selenium to dismiss this "download is pending" dialog?

Ive tried

```js
edge: {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: "edge",
    browser_version: "16.0",
    unhandledPromptBehavior: "accept",
  },
```

Comment: That code snippet does not run. It's not even valid Json. see [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to discuss here so let me unpack this a bit.

1. Is there an unhandled alert prompt handler?
   In the W3C specification for WebDriver there is such a configuration, however Edge doesn't currently support this and even if it did the prompt you're describing here isn't a prompt/alert/confirm but rather a browser UX prompt. That means the page itself won't be able to control it and neither will WebDriver.
2. Should WebDriver return from a navigation to a download link before the download has finished?
   If you compare Firefox/Chrome/Edge you'll notice that both Firefox/Edge don't return from a larger download navigation while Chrome does. The specification here isn't clear so I've file the following issue to discuss: https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1244
3. Should the Delete Session command cancel any in-progress downloads and dismiss any browser UX about cancelling those downloads and then close the browser?
   This is another gray area that will need to be clarified in the specification. It could be useful for a developer who has out-of-browser validation if they had some estimate of when the download was complete to validate it was the right binary or what not. It could also be useful just to validate the download occurred and then cancel it.

Once the spec issue has been discussed and settled on the browser vendors will work towards whatever the determined fix is.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not required to verify the prompt, I suggest changing the settings in the browser to download without asking:

1. Open the Microsoft Edge app.
2. Click on the More actions button at the top right corner, and click on Settings.
3. Click on View advanced settings.
4. Under Downloads, turn off ***Always ask me what to do with each download*** for what you want.

Also, you may try adding this capability to your framework:

***UnhandledAlertException*** which possible values are "accept", "dismiss" and "ignore"